# to get value from the function to the global function

Tags: java, android, function, parameters

here i'm having a function Actionmodecallback having 4 different parameters and i wants to store the value of position in my global variable but whenever i'm doing this the value comes out to be 0 always but the values of the other parameters is fine except the position variable

```
Context _context, _active;
    ActionMode _mActionMode;
    ArrayList<String> _array_list;
    ListView _list;
    public int _position_list;

    public ActionModeCallback(Context context, ArrayList<String> array_list,
            ListView list, ActionMode mActionMode, int position) {
        super();
        this._context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this._mActionMode = mActionMode;
        this._array_list = array_list;
        this._list = list;
        this._position_list = position;
        this._active = context;

    }
```

Comment: Where calling `ActionModeCallback` method ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? If you pass 0, then it is pretty normal you get 0. You may also want to read up on some basic terminology: Java doesn't have functions, but methods. Also, there are no global variables in Java.
What you refer to are instance variables. Is there a reason why that particular variable is declared to be public?

Comment: i'm a beginner and i have tried debugging and i have seen the value of position is 2 and in the same line the value of this._position_list is 0